# google play console vs firebase analytucs dau's - why different?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-play, firebase-analytics, google-developers-console

I have a very direct question, why are google play console and firebase dau numbers so different? I can't find the full definitions of what makes up each dau. However considering both are "Google" numbers, quite weird to see such a large difference.